# Reverse geocoding is not working in some android devices?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-geocoder

I am developing an application on maps, am not able to get address in this mobile, its android version is 4.3, like below --

[image: example]

But it is working fine in my mobile, its version is 4.1.2, like below --

[image: example]

It is working fine in some lollipop versions.

```
    final Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                if (address.getAddressLine(i).equals("null")) {

                } else {
                    sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                    sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                    //sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
                    //sb.append(address.getCountryName());
                }
            }
           // Toast.makeText(RegistrationTest.this, "Text Address is " + sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            text_address = sb.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Toast.makeText(RegistrationTest.this, "exception " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Sorry for my english, and thank you for your time and help!

Please help me, am stuck here!

Comment: There have been some issues with Geocoder failing, a bug was submitted here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9153 . Maybe that is your problem. You can always get your address via google web service.

Comment: Thank your. got the solution

Answer (score 4):

Geocoder is not working in some devices. So, we need to create a custom Geocoder. You can check if Geocoder is implemented by the manufactures of the device with [Geocoder.isPresent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#isPresent()) but the method is unreliable. We can't ensure the Geocoder is implemented wit it.

For custom Geocoder, you can use the following class which the usage is exactly like using the Geocoder:

```
import android.location.Address;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MyGeocoder {

  public static final String TAG = MyGeocoder.class.getSimpleName();

  static OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

  public static List<Address> getFromLocation(double lat, double lng, int maxResult) {

    String address = String.format(Locale.US,
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%1$f,%2$f&sensor=false&language="
            + Locale.getDefault().getCountry(), lat, lng);
    Log.d(TAG, "address = " + address);
    Log.d(TAG, "Locale.getDefault().getCountry() = " + Locale.getDefault().getCountry());

    return getAddress(address, maxResult);

  }

  public static List<Address> getFromLocationName(String locationName, int maxResults)  {

    String address = null;
    try {
      address = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + URLEncoder.encode(locationName,
          "UTF-8") + "&ka&sensor=false";
      return getAddress(address, maxResults);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }

  private static List<Address> getAddress(String url, int maxResult) {
    List<Address> retList = null;

    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url)
        .header("User-Agent", "OkHttp Headers.java")
        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json; q=0.5")
        .build();
    try {
      Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
      String responseStr = response.body().string();
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseStr);

      retList = new ArrayList<Address>();

      if ("OK".equalsIgnoreCase(jsonObject.getString("status"))) {
        JSONArray results = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
        if (results.length() > 0) {
          for (int i = 0; i < results.length() && i < maxResult; i++) {
            JSONObject result = results.getJSONObject(i);
            Address addr = new Address(Locale.getDefault());

            JSONArray components = result.getJSONArray("address_components");
            String streetNumber = "";
            String route = "";
            for (int a = 0; a < components.length(); a++) {
              JSONObject component = components.getJSONObject(a);
              JSONArray types = component.getJSONArray("types");
              for (int j = 0; j < types.length(); j++) {
                String type = types.getString(j);
                if (type.equals("locality")) {
                  addr.setLocality(component.getString("long_name"));
                } else if (type.equals("street_number")) {
                  streetNumber = component.getString("long_name");
                } else if (type.equals("route")) {
                  route = component.getString("long_name");
                }
              }
            }
            addr.setAddressLine(0, route + " " + streetNumber);

            addr.setLatitude(
                result.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lat"));
            addr.setLongitude(
                result.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lng"));
            retList.add(addr);
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error calling Google geocode webservice.", e);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error parsing Google geocode webservice response.", e);
    }

    return retList;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Geocoder is not implemented by all manufacturers. It's may be a reason why it doesn't work on a particular device. From the [`Geocoder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) documentation :

> The Geocoder class requires a backend service that is not included in the core android framework. The Geocoder query methods will return an empty list if there no backend service in the platform

Or perhaps there is a request quota.

Instead you can use a remote service like [Google Maps geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Geocoding) (quotas too).