# How to resolve error "reverse geo fail" in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, geolocation, reverse-geocoding

My phone *xiaomi redmi note 2*, have a lollipop operating system (API 21).
How to take the coordinates of my points and translate them to the corresponding address? Why in my gadget can not run and error "reverse geo fail" appears, but in other gadgets run very well. 
I have minSdkVersion 21 in settings gradle.

the following code

```
public class Emergency extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

   protected LocationManager locationManager;
   ProgressDialog loading;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_emergency);

       if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 101);
       }
   }

   //onClick button
   public void btn_pick_up(View view) {
       android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
       alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure");
       alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
       alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

               loading = ProgressDialog.show(Emergency.this, "Loading", "Please wait", false, false);
               getLocation();
           }
       });

       alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {}
       });

       android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
       alertDialog.show();
   }

   void getLocation() {
       try {
           locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
           assert locationManager != null;
           locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 5, this);

       } catch(SecurityException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           loading.dismiss();
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
       Toast.makeText(Emergency.this, "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + "\n Longitude: " + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       try {
           Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
           List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
           Toast.makeText(Emergency.this,
                addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0) +", "+
                        addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) +", "+
                        addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
           loading.dismiss();
       } catch(Exception e) {
           Toast.makeText(Emergency.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           loading.dismiss();
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
       Toast.makeText(Emergency.this, "Please Enable GPS and Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   @Override
   public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

   @Override
   public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
       Toast.makeText(Emergency.this, "GPS Enable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
```

Comment: Up, help me please

Comment: does the code run well on your gadget? help me please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse geocoding is not working in some android devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332594/reverse-geocoding-is-not-working-in-some-android-devices)

Comment: it turns out my gadget with GPS problem